# Authorize.net account changing

Tags: payment, authorize.net, refund

I have question to our respective community related to Authorize.net. I am not sure it related to Magento or nor, but if you have some experience, please, guide me. 
We have changed our Authorize.net account's business name and bank account, and also we are going to switch to new Authorize.net account. But here problem is that we don't know how our previous payments will be handled. Our store uses refunding payments actively. If we switch to new account, will it affect to previous account payment refunds? Or is there some extension or functionality of Magento which handles this situation? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of the change will depend on whether or not you have orders with pending authorizations in your system or not. If you have been capturing funds upon order placement, you should be fine if you keep a few things in mind. If, however, you have orders in your system with open / uncaptured authorizations, I would recommend invoicing those orders before making the change if possible.

Once changing the API credentials in Magento, it will no longer be able to talk to the old Authorize.net account. Transactions placed under the old account will not work with the new account since it wasn't the one used to process them.

You'll still be able to invoice and refund existing orders, but when when you do there will be an added step. When invoicing them in Magento, you'll want to make sure to check the box to invoice or refund "offline" and then follow up with that by logging into the Authorize.net account, looking up the associated transaction, and manually issuing the refund and/or capturing the authorization.

Answer (score 1):

To perform refunds on cards that have not been charged on your active authorize.net account, you need to apply for extended credit capabilities (ECC). You can find the application here: [www.authorize.net/files/ecc.pdf](http://www.authorize.net/files/ecc.pdf)